# Using Google Web Fonts Locally

Tags: css

My theme has following code:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,300italic,400italic");
```

This font doesn't support Turkish characters so I downloaded one that supports Turkish characters. However the theme has problems about showing bold and strong fonts.

I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: '../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold';
      src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
      src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
           url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
           url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */

     font-weight: bold;
     font-style: normal;
}
```

How can I show bold and strong tags using my theme?

Comment: There's no reason to use `font-weight:bold;` since that's already a bold font. Also, font-family should just be the name of the font, not a file path. IE `font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Bold';`

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried this: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/388527/   but all text became bold

Comment: All the text using that font family is going to be bold, because it's a bold font. If you want the regular version of the font, you will have to define that font separately.

Comment: yes, I edited the answer, http://sudrap.org/paste/text/388527/

Comment: All of your fonts have the same font-family name. You need to have different names for each variation of the font. Like SourceSansPro-Regular, SourceSansPro-Black, SourceSansPro-Bold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off your latest update, here is how you would do it:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url(font-awesome.min.css);
@font-face {
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Regular';
  src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Black';
  src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Black.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Black.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Black.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Black.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Bold';
  src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Then let's say you wanted the H1s to be bold and the P tags to be regular, the CSS would look like this:

```
h1 { font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Bold'; }
p { font-family: 'SourceSansPro-Regular'; }
```

Comment: &subset=latin-ext for google font works better. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro';
      src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
      src: url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
           url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
           url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
           url('../fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */

     font-weight: bold;
     font-style: normal;
}
```

Notice the name of the font-family. That name should match the name from Google Fonts.

[Here's an article about it](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-use-font-face-avoid-faux-italic-and-bold-browser-styles)

Comment: thanks for the answer, I upvoted it, both answers work fine. I have to find appropiate fonts for h1s buttons strongs because my theme doesn't use bold property, it uses numbers.